# What is the best method to secure a Wireless Access Point in a Windows domain?

Tags: networking, security, wifi

We have a Windows based site running Windows Server 2012. We have ZyXEL NWA1123-AC access points that up until now we've allowed people to use on laptops, mobile phones etc. We have been using a password but had been giving out as needed.

We want to change our policy to only allowing company issued laptops to connect to our wireless network (even company issued mobiles will no longer be included).

The issue with changing the password and re-connecting the laptops is that anyone can go in and view the password (a 2 second search: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+to+view+wifi+password&oq=how+to+view+wifi+password&aqs=chrome..69i57.2655j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

What is the best method to secure a Wireless Access Point (without passwords I assume), so that we can restrict it to company issued laptops?

Answer (score 1):

The best method is implementing WPA2-Enterprise with Radius Server (Network Policy Server on Windows Server).

You can configure WPA2-Enterprise in a few ways e.g. username and password for each person from their account in AD, certificate based or machine authentication.

On enterprise access points you can also use Radius based VLANs for each device based on permissions assigned to the user or machine.

WPA2-PSK is for home use only.

Comment: I have checked and unfortunately WPA2-Enterprise doesn't seem to be an option on this device (at least I can't see it in the security settings).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way but the simplest I can think of relies on RADIUS and MAC address. I found this link http://kb.zyxel.com/KB/searchArticle!gwsViewDetail.action?articleOid=007988&lang=EN on Zyxel site.